# Control Launcher icon visibility at runtime

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which shows three separate activity icons in the device Launcher screen.

Is it possible to toggle the visibility of a couple of the Launcher icon(s) based on settings chosen in one of the activity screens during runtime?

Comment: i dont feel you can change the manifest file and the launcher icon/icons for activities are set in manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html):

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public static void enableComponent(Context context, Class<?> componentClass,
        boolean enabled) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(context, componentClass),
            enabled ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
                    : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

(Use `YourActivity.class` for the second parameter `componentClass`).

Note that old Androids need to restart to take effect. I tested on Android 4.x and it applied immediately.